# Select random range for respawning according to screen size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn targets at random spots. When I input exact values such as (-4,4) it works fine but it is not going to help if I am going to try that on different screen sizes.

I tried to to define the range according to the screen size but this time the targets doesn't appear on the screen at all. Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3), Random.Range(-4, 4), 0); //works

Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(Screen.width/10, (Screen.width/10) * 9), Random.Range(Screen.height/10, (Screen.height/10) * 9), 0); //doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line suggests that the origin of your plane is at `(0,0)` and it's the middle point of the screen. In that case the correct code would look similar to this:

```
Vector3 position = new Vector3(
    Random.Range(-1 * Screen.width/2, Screen.width/2),
    Random.Range(-1 * Screen.height/2, Screen.height/2), 0);
```

Comment: Yes the plane origin is set to (0,0). To check, for example if the screen width is 10 - the extreme most left is 0 and extreme most right is 10 for the width (0,10) right?  If yes, the above will give the results for x-axis as (-1,1) which would be wrong.

Comment: @keshk If ranges like `(-3,3)` are giving correct results, then it's obvious that for screen of width `10` the most left is `-5` not `0`, and most right is `5`. I leaved your scaling factor, I thought you needed it for something. It's easy to rescale it back - check my edit.

Comment: Silly mistake. I have yet to try the edited code but I get the concept. Thanks.